# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_unregister_GLOBALS() when upgrading to 5.5

Tags: windows, wordpress-5.5, wordpress

I have WordPress running on Windows 10 with IIS.

While upgrading WordPress to 5.5 this morning I received the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_unregister_GLOBALS() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-settings.php:70 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-config.php(92): require_once() #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...') #2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...') #3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-admin\index.php(10): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-settings.php on line 70

Answer (score 1):

This was a very easy fix. Since my installation was local I just copied all the files and directories located in the WordPress 5.5 upgrade folder (in my case it was ***C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-content\upgrade\wordpress-5.5-no-content-cIBdh3\wordpress***) to the root of the site (in my case ***C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress***) overwriting the file already there.

Very simple fix. I guess the installation hit something while it was copying or timedout, who knows. I'm sure you can do the same thing by FTPing to your site if you are hosting your site remotely.

Answer (score 0):

i am updating to 5.5 in my hostiing and i got this problem, the solution is **You should upload all and folder file update** except wp-content but it depends

Answer (score 0):

It might happen during update when the new version of Wordpress or new version of plugin does encounter any issue. What will work then is to find the files of the problematic plugin and temporary change it's names and then try to run WP admin again. For me it was one folder and two files outside of this folder which were belonging to the failing plugin.

The error details gives you hint where to search for. But I think it would be recommended to turn the wordress Debugging mode off, so next time anything crashes there will be no such details visible until you turn debugging mode on